# Prediction classes not showing in app (Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.)

Tags: javascript, class

I made a plant leaf diseases classification using transfer learning MobileNet, i saved my model as h5 the converted it into .js, in the app I changed classes.js to fit the SoftMax of my model which was 38 classes.

**Actual Result : When I run the app it does not show the classes *image2* , it jus shows the probabilities , but interestingly when I put classes.js with ImageNet classes , classes appear in app .**

where am I going wrong ? How do I get classes from my model to appear in the predictions .

**The expected result: is to have the app show both classes(From my class disease softmax output) and probability % .**

I have attaches files below.

[[image: error in console]

### **Actual result**

[[image: Probabilities with no Classes]

### **result with imagenet classes.js**

[image]

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  Alert, Button, Collapse, Container, Form, Spinner, ListGroup, Tabs, Tab
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FaCamera, FaChevronDown, FaChevronRight } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { openDB } from 'idb';
import Cropper  from 'react-cropper';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import LoadButton from '../components/LoadButton';
import { MODEL_CLASSES } from '../model/classes';
import config from '../config';
import './Classify.css';
import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';


const MODEL_PATH = '/model/model.json';
const IMAGE_SIZE = 224;
const CANVAS_SIZE = 224;
const TOPK_PREDICTIONS = 5;

const INDEXEDDB_DB = 'tensorflowjs';
const INDEXEDDB_STORE = 'model_info_store';
const INDEXEDDB_KEY = 'web-model';

/**
 * Class to handle the rendering of the Classify page.
 * @extends React.Component
 */
export default class Classify extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.webcam = null;
    this.model = null;
    this.modelLastUpdated = null;

    this.state = {
      modelLoaded: false,
      filename: '',
      isModelLoading: false,
      isClassifying: false,
      predictions: [],
      photoSettingsOpen: true,
      modelUpdateAvailable: false,
      showModelUpdateAlert: false,
      showModelUpdateSuccess: false,
      isDownloadingModel: false
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (('indexedDB' in window)) {
      try {
        this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('indexeddb://' + INDEXEDDB_KEY);

        // Safe to assume tensorflowjs database and related object store exists.
        // Get the date when the model was saved.
        try {
          const db = await openDB(INDEXEDDB_DB, 1, );
          const item = await db.transaction(INDEXEDDB_STORE)
                               .objectStore(INDEXEDDB_STORE)
                               .get(INDEXEDDB_KEY);
          const dateSaved = new Date(item.modelArtifactsInfo.dateSaved);
          await this.getModelInfo();
          console.log(this.modelLastUpdated);
          if (!this.modelLastUpdated  || dateSaved >= new Date(this.modelLastUpdated).getTime()) {
            console.log('Using saved model');
          }
          else {
            this.setState({
              modelUpdateAvailable: true,
              showModelUpdateAlert: true,
            });
          }

        }
        catch (error) {
          console.warn(error);
          console.warn('Could not retrieve when model was saved.');
        }

      }
      // If error here, assume that the object store doesn't exist and the model currently isn't
      // saved in IndexedDB.
      catch (error) {
        console.log('Not found in IndexedDB. Loading and saving...');
        console.log(error);
        this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_PATH);
        await this.model.save('indexeddb://' + INDEXEDDB_KEY);
      }
    }
    // If no IndexedDB, then just download like normal.
    else {
      console.warn('IndexedDB not supported.');
      this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_PATH);
    }

    this.setState({ modelLoaded: true });
    this.initWebcam();

    // Warm up model.
    let prediction = tf.tidy(() => this.model.predict(tf.zeros([1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3])));
    prediction.dispose();
  }

  async componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.webcam) {
      this.webcam.stop();
    }

    // Attempt to dispose of the model.
    try {
      this.model.dispose();
    }
    catch (e) {
      // Assume model is not loaded or already disposed.
    }
  }

  initWebcam = async () => {
    try {
      this.webcam = await tf.data.webcam(
        this.refs.webcam,
        {resizeWidth: CANVAS_SIZE, resizeHeight: CANVAS_SIZE, facingMode: 'environment'}
      );
    }
    catch (e) {
      this.refs.noWebcam.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

  startWebcam = async () => {
    if (this.webcam) {
      this.webcam.start();
    }
  }

  stopWebcam = async () => {
    if (this.webcam) {
      this.webcam.stop();
    }
  }

  getModelInfo = async () => {
    await fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/model_info`, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
      await response.json().then((data) => {
        this.modelLastUpdated = data.last_updated;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to get parse model info.');
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Unable to get model info');
    });
  }

  updateModel = async () => {
    // Get the latest model from the server and refresh the one saved in IndexedDB.
    console.log('Updating the model: ' + INDEXEDDB_KEY);
    this.setState({ isDownloadingModel: true });
    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_PATH);
    await this.model.save('indexeddb://' + INDEXEDDB_KEY);
    this.setState({
      isDownloadingModel: false,
      modelUpdateAvailable: false,
      showModelUpdateAlert: false,
      showModelUpdateSuccess: true
    });
  }

  classifyLocalImage = async () => {
    this.setState({ isClassifying: true });

    const croppedCanvas = this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    const image = tf.tidy( () => tf.browser.fromPixels(croppedCanvas).toFloat());

    // Process and resize image before passing in to model.
    const imageData = await this.processImage(image);
    const resizedImage = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageData, [IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE]);

    const logits = this.model.predict(resizedImage);
    const probabilities = await logits.data();
    const preds = await this.getTopKClasses(probabilities, TOPK_PREDICTIONS);

    this.setState({
      predictions: preds,
      isClassifying: false,
      photoSettingsOpen: !this.state.photoSettingsOpen
    });

    // Draw thumbnail to UI.
    const context = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
    const ratioX = CANVAS_SIZE / croppedCanvas.width;
    const ratioY = CANVAS_SIZE / croppedCanvas.height;
    const ratio = Math.min(ratioX, ratioY);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_SIZE, CANVAS_SIZE);
    context.drawImage(croppedCanvas, 0, 0,
                      croppedCanvas.width * ratio, croppedCanvas.height * ratio);

    // Dispose of tensors we are finished with.
    image.dispose();
    imageData.dispose();
    resizedImage.dispose();
    logits.dispose();
  }

  classifyWebcamImage = async () => {
    this.setState({ isClassifying: true });

    const imageCapture = await this.webcam.capture();

    const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageCapture, [IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE]);
    const imageData = await this.processImage(resized);
    const logits = this.model.predict(imageData);
    const probabilities = await logits.data();
    const preds = await this.getTopKClasses(probabilities, TOPK_PREDICTIONS);

    this.setState({
      predictions: preds,
      isClassifying: false,
      photoSettingsOpen: !this.state.photoSettingsOpen
    });

    // Draw thumbnail to UI.
    const tensorData = tf.tidy(() => imageCapture.toFloat().div(255));
    await tf.browser.toPixels(tensorData, this.refs.canvas);

    // Dispose of tensors we are finished with.
    resized.dispose();
    imageCapture.dispose();
    imageData.dispose();
    logits.dispose();
    tensorData.dispose();
  }

  processImage = async (image) => {
    return tf.tidy(() => image.expandDims(0).toFloat().div(127).sub(1));
  }

  /**
   * Computes the probabilities of the topK classes given logits by computing
   * softmax to get probabilities and then sorting the probabilities.
   * @param logits Tensor representing the logits from MobileNet.
   * @param topK The number of top predictions to show.
   */
  getTopKClasses = async (values, topK) => {
    const valuesAndIndices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      valuesAndIndices.push({value: values[i], index: i});
    }
    valuesAndIndices.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.value - a.value;
    });
    const topkValues = new Float32Array(topK);
    const topkIndices = new Int32Array(topK);
    for (let i = 0; i < topK; i++) {
      topkValues[i] = valuesAndIndices[i].value;
      topkIndices[i] = valuesAndIndices[i].index;
    }

    const topClassesAndProbs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < topkIndices.length; i++) {
      topClassesAndProbs.push({
        className: MODEL_CLASSES[topkIndices[i]],
        probability: (topkValues[i] * 100).toFixed(2)
      });
    }
    return topClassesAndProbs;
  }

  handlePanelClick = event => {
    this.setState({ photoSettingsOpen: !this.state.photoSettingsOpen });
  }

  handleFileChange = event => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.setState({
        file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
        filename: event.target.files[0].name
      });
    }
  }

  handleTabSelect = activeKey => {
    switch(activeKey) {
      case 'camera':
        this.startWebcam();
        break;
      case 'localfile':
        this.setState({filename: null, file: null});
        this.stopWebcam();
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Classify container">

      { !this.state.modelLoaded &&
        <Fragment>
          <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
            <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
          </Spinner>
          {' '}<span className="loading-model-text">Loading Model</span>
        </Fragment>
      }

      { this.state.modelLoaded &&
        <Fragment>
        <Button
          onClick={this.handlePanelClick}
          className="classify-panel-header"
          aria-controls="photo-selection-pane"
          aria-expanded={this.state.photoSettingsOpen}
          >
          Take or Select a Photo to Classify
            <span className='panel-arrow'>
            { this.state.photoSettingsOpen
              ? <FaChevronDown />
              : <FaChevronRight />
            }
            </span>
          </Button>
          <Collapse in={this.state.photoSettingsOpen}>
            <div id="photo-selection-pane">
            { this.state.modelUpdateAvailable && this.state.showModelUpdateAlert &&
                <Container>
                  <Alert
                    variant="info"
                    show={this.state.modelUpdateAvailable && this.state.showModelUpdateAlert}
                    onClose={() => this.setState({ showModelUpdateAlert: false})}
                    dismissible>
                      An update for the <strong>{this.state.modelType}</strong> model is available.
                      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center pt-1">
                        {!this.state.isDownloadingModel &&
                          <Button onClick={this.updateModel}
                                  variant="outline-info">
                            Update
                          </Button>
                        }
                        {this.state.isDownloadingModel &&
                          <div>
                            <Spinner animation="border" role="status" size="sm">
                              <span className="sr-only">Downloading...</span>
                            </Spinner>
                            {' '}<strong>Downloading...</strong>
                          </div>
                        }
                      </div>
                  </Alert>
                </Container>
              }
              {this.state.showModelUpdateSuccess &&
                <Container>
                  <Alert variant="success"
                         onClose={() => this.setState({ showModelUpdateSuccess: false})}
                         dismissible>
                    The <strong>{this.state.modelType}</strong> model has been updated!
                  </Alert>
                </Container>
              }
            <Tabs defaultActiveKey="camera" id="input-options" onSelect={this.handleTabSelect}
                  className="justify-content-center">
              <Tab eventKey="camera" title="Take Photo">
                <div id="no-webcam" ref="noWebcam">
                  <span className="camera-icon"><FaCamera /></span>
                  No camera found. <br />
                  Please use a device with a camera, or upload an image instead.
                </div>
                <div className="webcam-box-outer">
                  <div className="webcam-box-inner">
                    <video ref="webcam" autoPlay playsInline muted id="webcam"
                           width="448" height="448">
                    </video>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="button-container">
                  <LoadButton
                    variant="primary"
                    size="lg"
                    onClick={this.classifyWebcamImage}
                    isLoading={this.state.isClassifying}
                    text="Classify"
                    loadingText="Classifying..."
                  />
                </div>
              </Tab>
              <Tab eventKey="localfile" title="Select Local File">
                <Form.Group controlId="file">
                  <Form.Label>Select Image File</Form.Label><br />
                  <Form.Label className="imagelabel">
                    {this.state.filename ? this.state.filename : 'Browse...'}
                  </Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    onChange={this.handleFileChange}
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/*"
                    className="imagefile" />
                </Form.Group>
                { this.state.file &&
                  <Fragment>
                    <div id="local-image">
                      <Cropper
                        ref="cropper"
                        src={this.state.file}
                        style={{height: 400, width: '100%'}}
                        guides={true}
                        aspectRatio={1 / 1}
                        viewMode={2}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="button-container">
                      <LoadButton
                        variant="primary"
                        size="lg"
                        disabled={!this.state.filename}
                        onClick={this.classifyLocalImage}
                        isLoading={this.state.isClassifying}
                        text="Classify"
                        loadingText="Classifying..."
                      />
                    </div>
                  </Fragment>
                }
              </Tab>
            </Tabs>
            </div>
          </Collapse>
          { this.state.predictions.length > 0 &&
            <div className="classification-results">
              <h3>Predictions</h3>
              <canvas ref="canvas" width={CANVAS_SIZE} height={CANVAS_SIZE} />
              <br />
              <ListGroup>
              {this.state.predictions.map((category) => {
                  return (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={category.className}>
                      <strong>{category.className}</strong> {category.probability}%</ListGroup.Item>
                  );
              })}
              </ListGroup>
            </div>
          }
          </Fragment>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://sentry.io/answers/unique-key-prop/

Comment: Thanks !So this UI goes in my classify.js ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've got a react component with something like `{items.map(item => <div>{item.value}</div>}` that should be changed to something like `{items.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.value}</div>}` instead.

Comment: The code in the link does go in your js file, yes. Not sure classify.js is the correct js file but I'm guessing you've only got 1 js file?

Comment: yes it actually looks like this : 
<ListGroup>
              {this.state.predictions.map((category) => {
                  return (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={category.className}>
                      <strong>{category.className}</strong> {category.probability}%</ListGroup.Item>
                  );
              })}
              </ListGroup>

Comment: Are you sure `category.className` is unique for every item in `this.state.predictions`? The error is saying `key` (so really `category.className`) is not always unique.

Comment: this.state = { predictions: []}, is an empty array , should className be in there ?

Comment: If it's empty, then every item is unique (because there aren't any) so I see no problem having predictions be an empty array.

Comment: that is what i am failing to figure out , but when i put in a different classes.js from a different model they show up in the app!

Comment: that error will never run when you map over an empty array. it only occurs if it has content, and you have a duplicating key. I would not recommend use as key `className` since it's likely to have duplications.

Comment: @buzatto yes i have tried to change it , still the same thing! The weird thing is when a load a different classes.js file with classes from ImageNet it works and classes now appear in the app, But i am using a different model "mobilenet transfer learning"

Comment: your initial state could be empty, then when it gets updated,  predictions is no longer empty. I would suggest to comment the code where it breaks and `console.log(this.state.prediction(this.state.predictions)` on component update to verify its value

Comment: @buzatto it didn't help , would you mind checking the full code here https://github.com/IBM/tfjs-web-app/issues/17 may be you might spot the error

Comment: @Rocky Sims can you please review the code here for more context https://github.com/IBM/tfjs-web-app/issues/17

Comment: @KudzayiVictorKing I think what you actually need is a quick lesson on how to approach fixing bugs. You need to define super clearly the ACTUAL vs EXPECTED result. Trust me, it'll help you zero in on the problem. Describe precisely what you expect to happen under EXPECTED and then under ACTUAL describe what actually happened instead. Rephrase your trouble in terms of EXPECTED vs ACTUAL and add that to your question (and comment down here to let me know).

Comment: @RockySims Thanks for the feedback , i have redacted my question made it more clear as much as i could please check.

Comment: So it sounds like you expected the category name to appear to the left of each `category.probability` and what's actually happening is only the probability is shown (without a category name). If that's the case, then the warning about how every key should be unique is not really the problem. Try adding `console.log('category:', category)` right after `{this.state.predictions.map((category) => {` and before the `return`. I'm guessing `category` has no `.className`. What does the `category` it logs in the console look like?

Comment: @RockySims the logs say 
Unable to get model info
Classify.js:66 null
Classify.js:68 Using saved model
Classify.js:442 category: {className: undefined, probability: "20.44"}

Comment: It's usually best to fix the first error first which in this case is "Unable to get model info" which indicates that `fetch(${config.API_ENDPOINT}/model_info, ...` is failing. Try changing `console.log('Unable to get model info');` to `console.log('Unable to get model info because:', err);` and see what error the endpoint is returning.

Comment: @RockySims  `Classify.js:146 GET http://localhost:5000/api/model_info 500 (Internal Server Error)` this is what it says .

Comment: Hmm... not a very informative error. Are you running a node server via a terminal command such as `node server.js` or something similar? If so, it's looking like the error is in the server.js file.

Comment: @Rocky Sims I am using `yarn start-dev` I haven't run it thru  `node server.js` there is also an error saying `Category: object className undefined`.

Comment: @RockySims Hi! I finally solved that error! the `model` was actually not working , the predictions were coming from a preloaded model that was in `indexedDB` , hence it could not read the `classe.js` for my model. I just deleted the model in `indexedDB` reloaded then it saved my new model to `indexedDB` , all errors disappeared and all classes appear as required. 

I have decided to add another `function` to the `app`, i want to display `Treatment Methods`  when a person presses the `Prediction` , what is the best was of achieving this in React?